# rule for validating $ amount?

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

A web site uses jQuery Validation which I'm new to. I like the way it works using rules and reusing them. I need to validate a field for money. It can be one of the following formats:

```
$100,000
$2500000
$3503.00
40000000
40033.00
```

Can you please help me how to create this rule.

Comment: jQuery Validate plugin is not the jQuery Validation Engine.  Which one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you're using [the jQuery Validate plugin](http://jqueryvalidation.org), you can simply use the `currency` rule/method as provided in [the `additional-methods.js` file](http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.13.0/additional-methods.js).

```
$("#form").validate({
    rules: {
        money: {
            currency: ['$', false]
        }
    }
});
```

The first parameter is the currency symbol and the second parameter is a boolean stating whether the currency symbol should be a mandatory part of the user's input.

**DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/dxrd4cp7/**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#form").validate({
    rules: {
      money: {
        currency: ['$', false]
      }
    }
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.13.0/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.13.0/additional-methods.js"></script>


<form id="form">
  <input type="text" name="money" />
  <br/>
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```